# Error in awarding Enlightened Badge

Tags: support, badges

I have 4 non-wiki answers to questions which are accepted and also have a score of $10$ or more. These are as follows:

[image]

But I have earned the **Enlightened Badge** only $3$ times.

[image]

Can anyone explain this? Is this a bug?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The description of the badge, quoted in your own screenshot, says in part "First to answer".

For one of those questions, your answer was 3rd to be posted, as the [question's timeline](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/1501800/timeline) shows.

Comment: Just noticed it. Thanks.....